# Event for Add to Wishlist button in Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, wishlist

I want to redirect User to Observer on **Add to Wishlist** Click

i want this for guest users

**Example**
if customer is not logged in then it must redirect user same page

So far i have tried Following Events

```
 - wishlist_add_product
 - wishlist_add_item
 - wishlist_product_add_after
```

i am not Getting any solution

Comment: Add exact query what your requirement? You can use dispatch events.

Comment: i  want to dispatch event when a add to wishlist is pressed

Comment: You can do it by ajax to dispatch event inside controller.

Comment: For logged-in users it will work by default, here you mean the guest users?

Comment: yes i want for guest users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plugin for that instead of event and apply your code logic for redirection :

> **app/code/RH/CustomPlugin/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Plugin">
        <plugin name="guest_wishlist_plugin" type="RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin\GuestPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> **app/code/RH/CustomPlugin/Plugin/GuestPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace RH\CustomPlugin\Plugin;

class GuestPlugin {

    public function beforeBeforeDispatch(\Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Plugin $coreSubject, $subject, $request) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Rohan.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');
        //Apply your code logic
        return [$subject, $request];
    }

}
```

Comment: not getting success :(

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Comment: Now, It should be working :) Because, I tested this code.

Comment: Thank you its working fine

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :)